# Conditional expectation in a non-filtered probability space

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The question I have is in the image below:

[image]

If $\mathcal{F}_n \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$ this would be a trivial problem, but this is obviously not guaranteed.  I thought of maybe defining $\mathcal{G}_i \equiv \sigma \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^i \mathcal{F}_j\right)$ but this isn't really helpful.  So instead perhaps I thought put $\mathcal{H}_i \equiv \bigcap_{j=1}^i\mathcal{F}_i$ and this yields that $$E(X_i|\mathcal{H}_i) = E(X_1|\mathcal{H}_i) $$ but I'm convinced this isn't helpful either.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you take your problem from?

Comment: From a practice exam I found online.  I downloaded them all a really long time ago so I'm not actually certain which link it can be found at on the web but I just uploaded it so you can view the full thing here: https://www.docdroid.net/CgJQlhb/prob-qual-pdf

Comment: Nice, thanks =)

Comment: No worries.  Do you have any ideas about the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to show:

$E[[X | Y] | Z] = X$ implies $E[X | Y] = X$ a.s.  If you have this, you can further induct to get your solution.

To show this, note that what you are trying to show is equivalent to showing:

$E[ (E[X | Y] - X)^2 ] = 0$.

Now, let us rewrite that as

$E[ (E[X | Y] - X)(E[X | Y] - X) ] = 0$.

which means

$E[ E[X | Y](E[X | Y] - X) ] - E[X (E[X | Y] - X)] = 0$.

So, the first one is $0$ by the definition of conditioning on $Y$, since E[X | Y] is Y measurable, and the difference X - E[X | Y] has to be orthogonal to all Y measurable functions.

For the second term, we rewrite it as:

$E[X (E[X | Y] - X)] = E[X (E[X | Y] - E[E[X | Y]|Z])]$

but again, noting that $X$ is Z measurable implies that this quantity has to be 0.

For the general case, let's try a different proof strategy:

We have, since squaring is a contraction for conditional expectations,

$$X^2 \leq E[(X | F_n | ... | F_i)^2 | ... | F_1] \leq ... \leq E[X^2 | F_n | ... | F_1]$$

Taking expectations of both sides, we see that the inequalities have to be equalities almost surely, i.e. we have

$$ X^2 = E[(X | F_n | ... | F_2)^2 | F_1]$$

Our goal is to show that

$E[(X - E[(X | F_n | ... | F_2)^2]$ = 0, so we want to have

$$E[ E[(X^2 + E[(X | F_n | ... | F_2)^2 - 2 X E[(X | F_n | ... | F_2) | F_1]]$$

Now, let us note that in $F_1$, the first two terms merge, so we have that that term equals to

$$ 2 E[ E[X | F_n | ... | F_1] (E[X | F_n | ... | F_1) - E[X| ... |F_2)]

However, this is 0 by the $F_1$ measurability of the conditional expectation.

This shows that $X_2 = X_1$ in the above question, so now we can induct on a smaller set.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this makes sense.  Just to clarify, since I really didn't seek to use induction initially:  our hypothesis is the statement:  $P(n)$ = "$X_{n+1} = X_1$ and $E(X_{i+1} | \mathcal{F}_i) = X_i \text{ a.s.}$ implies $X_i = X_1 \text{ a.s. } \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$".  Then $P(2)$ clearly holds by your proof and the rest is clear for if $P(n)$ holds and we have $X_{n+2} = X_1$ with $E(X_{i+1}|\mathcal{F}_i) = X_i$, then $X_{n+1} = X_1$ by $P(2)$ applied to $n+2, n+1$ and $n$ and then $X_1 = X_i$ for each $i$ since we assumed $P(n)$ to be true

Comment: Yeah, maybe there is a better way to do it, but that sounds about right!

Comment: Actually my comment is incorrect.  $P(2)$ cannot be applied to the indices $n+2, n+1$ and $n$ since we only have $$E(E(X_{n+2}|\mathcal{F}_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_n) = X_n$$ and this need not imply what I need here.  I'm sorry I'm still confused.  Even if we made the inductive hypothesis that $$E(E(... E(X|\mathcal{F}_n)| ... | \mathcal{F}_1) = X \implies E(X|\mathcal{F}_n) = X,$$ I fail to see how this can be used to show that $$E( ... E(X|\mathcal{F}_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_n)|... |\mathcal{F}_1) = X \implies E(X|\mathcal{F}_{n+1}) = X $$

Comment: hm I added a different proof; the other induction was indeed hard.

Comment: This makes complete sense.  I would never have seen the contraction trick myself though, so thank you.